# Struggling with Objected-Oriented Method

Tags: java

I can't figure it out what `getExits()` needs to be in order to get the output requested by the problem.

*//Constructor*

```
public class Room {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Room north;
    private Room east;
    private Room south;
    private Room west;

    public Room (String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Room getEast(){
        return this.east;
    }

    public String getExits (){
        //
    }   

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public Room getNorth(){
        return this.north;
    }

    public Room getWest(){
        return this.west;
    }

    public Room getSouth(){
        return this.south;
    }

    public void setExits (Room n, Room e, Room w, Room s){
        this.north = n;
        this.east = e;
        this.west = w;
        this.south = s;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s\n%s\n%s", this.name, this.description,getExits());
    }
}
```

*//Main Method*

```
public class Tester{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Room hall = new Room ("Hall", "It's Dark");
        Room bed = new Room ("Bed", "Tiny Room");
        Room bath = new Room ("Bath", "Toilets here");
        Room dine = new Room ("Dine", "Table and chairs");
        hall.setExits(bed, bath, dine, null);

        System.out.println(hall);

    }
}
```

Output expected:

```
Hall
It's Dark
North: Dine
East: Bath
West: Dining
```

Comment: Your method returns a single string. If you want to have multiple variables beeing returned you need to change the return type (array for example) or join the strings you want to return to a single one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing things. It's a little awkward because you have to check for null for each case - if that's not the case for you, you can remove those checks.

```
   public String getExits (){
       List<String> exits = new ArrayList<>();
        if (north != null) exits.add("North: " + north.name);
        if (south != null) exits.add("South: " + south.name);
        if (east != null) exits.add("East: " + east.name);
        if (west != null) exits.add("West: " + west.name);
        return String.join("\n", exits);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'Object Oriented' way of getting what you want would be to override the `toString()` method in your `Room` class such that it returns the *name* of the room.

You then modify the `getExits()`, like so:

```
public String getExits (){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(this.north != null) sb.append(this.north.toString()).append(" North") else sb.append("No Exit for: North");
    ...

    return sb.toString();
}
```

....

```
public class Room {
    private String name;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`exit` isn't something you can describe with a `String`. In the OO world, it should be a reference to a more meaningful object. I would go with

```
public Collection<Room> getExits();
```

or

```
public Map<String, Room> getExits();
```

which accurately describes where you can get from the hall. Here, we are assuming that "exit" is a doorway to another room.

You could return

```
Arrays.asList(northRoom, eastRoom, southRoom, westRoom);
```

or

```
Map<String, Room> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("north", northRoom);
...
return map;
```

Then you would be able to provide any `String` representation from the returned collection.

It's like a sign placed in the hall to help people navigate. Even though it can be replaced with another sign (a more detailed/accurate one), the structure of the building is constant, and you aren't altering it. You are just representing it differently.

```
String simpleSign = "You can go to: " + getExits().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.join(", "));
```

or

```
String detailedSign = "Directions to go: " + getExits().entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue().toString()).collect(Collectors.join("\n"));
```